# libcurl Set default CAPATH for every requests

Tags: curl, ssl-certificate, libcurl

The default built in CAPATH within the libcurl pkg doesn't work on my box and I have to use curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_CAPATH, "PATH_TO_CACERTS_DIR") on every request to get it successfully verified.

I am wondering if there is a way to set this globally and I don't have to set this for every request. I read some documentations about the global init for libcurl but haven't found any option to override this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only the built-in default path and the one you set per request. So if you want to avoid the per request set, you need to make sure that your libcurl is built with your preferred path as built-in default.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for your explanation.